# Intercepting a missile with unknown traveling direction

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, puzzle

A stealth missile is launched from space station, traveling in a straight line with fixed speed $V_s$. Being stealth the missile itself and its traveling direction is undetectable, but you know the position of the space station. At the same time the stealth missile is launched, you launch your own missile from another space station some distance $s$ away with maximum speed $V_m>V_s$.

Is there a way to design the trajectory of your missile so that it is guaranteed to intercept the stealth missile in finite time? If this can't be done, is a trajectory that gets arbitrarily close to the target in sufficient time possible?

Note: In two dimensions interception can be guaranteed by setting your missile to travel in some suitable logarithm spiral.

Comment: Can you assume that you know the location of the space station that the missile launched from?

Comment: @Paul, yes, the location is known. I've add that now.

Comment: Probably not: in two dimensions you have that a hyperplane (2-1=one dimension) can do something like that, so in three you probably need a surface

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414, that's how one feels. But reals on a line and on a plane can be made into one to one correspondence. So it must be the implicit requirement that your missile must go like a missile in a continuous curve that makes the situation impossible. But I can't make it more specific than that.

Comment: The space of the lines through the space station is the real projective plane, $\mathbb{R}P^2$, and a curve in this space can't be the whole space